# Maven OpenSAML dependency issue

Tags: maven, dependencies, opensaml

I have been assigned a task to implement SAML between my company and a client. I was looking at using OpenSAML but I am struggling to set up the maven project.

I add the dependency:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
<artifactId>opensaml</artifactId>
<version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

but the pom file has an error: Missing artifact xerces:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01

I cant find this dependency in the maven repository. When checking the OpenSAML site it states:

> Using OpenSAML in Maven-based Projects
>
> Following is the information necessary to use OpenSAML within
>   Maven-based projects. Maven Repository:
>   https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/repositories/releases Group
>   ID: org.opensaml Artifact ID: opensaml

But when i configure that respository in my pom file, it still cant find the dependency.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>org.opensaml</id>
      <url>https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </repository>
 </repositories>
```

Has anyone got OpenSAML set up in Maven that can help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you also added the xmltooling and openws dependencies to your POM file from the repository:

https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/opensaml/

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
<artifactId>xmltooling</artifactId>
<version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
<groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
<artifactId>openws</artifactId>
<version>1.4.2</version>
 </dependency>
```

The xmltooling should have the xerces xml-api that is missing.

Thanks,
Yogesh

Comment: To solve my problem i used three different versions of the opensaml, xmltooling and openws dependencies that are in maven AND do not rely on xerces. The dependencies are:

     <dependency>
   <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
   <artifactId>opensaml</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.1-1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
   <artifactId>openws</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.2-1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
   <artifactId>xmltooling</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.2-1</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: @Craig Are these the version numbers to use SAMLv2 ?